# JS Filter Contain

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

I am using [this](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/examples.php) ([file here](http://kirsehirilan.net/js/tablo.js)) script. It works fine and everything but it is currently filtering data using start with and I want it to filter using contains but I've looked at the documentation and inside the JS file and can't seem to find how to do it. Anyone has any ideas of what should I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the tablo.js file, the following lines:

```
        if (filters.nodeName=="INPUT" && filters.type=="text") {
            filters={ 'filter':"/^"+filters.value+"/" };
        }
```

Into this:

```
        if (filters.nodeName=="INPUT" && filters.type=="text") {
            filters={ 'filter':"/"+filters.value+"/" };
        }
```

Note the missing `^` which marks "start of the string".

**EDIT**: For case insensitive search, you can add the `i` flag to the RegExp constructor:

```
filter.filter = new RegExp(RegExp.$1, "i");
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info about RegExp.

Comment: Oh very simple solution, but it is important for me. I have a one more simple question. Script currently filtering data case sensitive. How i can remove this?